# Manipular preço em controle de estoque

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um sistema de controle de estoque em Java e me deparei com uma dúvida sobre como armazenar preços. Andei lendo que `double` e `float` não são bons para guardar este tipo de dado e sobre uma perda de dados ao fazer cálculos com eles. Então, o que usar?

Comment: você vai fazer conversão de moedas?

Comment: Não, irei armazenar os valores para mostrar em tabelas, realização de promoções etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como a manipulação de dinheiro necessita de cuidado realmente não é interessante usar pontos flutuantes, pois operações aritméticas com eles resultam em certas [imprecisões](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante#Problemas_com_o_uso_de_ponto_flutuante).

O tipo de dado recomendado para isso é o [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), em que você pode escolher o nível de precisão desejada. Diferentemente do `double` e do `float`, que utilizam a base binária e têm problemas para guardar números fracionários, o `BigDecimal` é mais adequado devido ao fato das manipulações se darem através do uso da base decimal.

Obs: devido aos problemas de imprecisão já mencionados, é sempre recomendado que se faça uso do construtor utilizando **String** como parâmetro, como no exemplo:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.1");
```

Answer (score 4):

Como recomendado por Martin Fowler em seu livro **Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture** você deve utilizar:

Um tipo inteiro com a quantia (1000 = R$ 10,00)
O tipo da moeda (Reais ou Dólares ).
Você deve evitar utilizar qualquer tipo de ponto flutuante pois isso poderá causar problemas de arredondamento que é o que você quer evitar. Nos cálculos você deve sempre levar em conta o tipo da moeda.

[Aqui](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) tem a pagina sobre o padrão de Martin Fowler

> Retirado do livro Padrões Arquiteturais Corporativos de Martin Fowler.
>
> Como Funciona
>
> A idéia básica é ter uma classe Dinheiro com campos para a quantidade numérica e a moeda corrente. Você pode armazenar a quantidade como um tipo inteiro ou um tipo decimal fixo. O tipo decimal é mais fácil para algumas manipulações, o integral para outras. Você deve evitar completamente qualquer tipo de ponto flutuante, pois isso introduzirá o tipo de problemas de arredondamento cuja finalidade de Dinheiro é evitar. Na maior parte do tempo, as pessoas querem valores monetários arredonda-dos para a menor unidade da moeda, como os centavos no dólar. Entretanto, há vezes em que unidades fracionárias são necessárias. É importante deixar claro com que tipo de dinheiro você está trabalhando, especialmente em uma aplicação que usa ambos os tipos. Faz sentido ter diferentes tipos para os dois casos, pois eles se comportam de forma bastante diferente no que diz respeito à aritmética.